# How to get the first value of the duplicate in this association list

Tags: associations

I have the following association list. I want to get the first value of the duplicate item, but only the last value. What should I do?

```
    Merge[{<|a -> 1, b -> 2, b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5, 
       c -> 2|>}, Last]
    Merge[{<|a -> 1, b -> 2, b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5, 
       c -> 2|>}, First](*The result I want is <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5|>*)
```

As Rohit Namjoshi said, can I first convert the relationship list to the normal list `{a -> 1, b -> 2, b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5, 
       c -> 2}` and then try to achieve the goal?

Comment: An `Association` cannot have duplicate keys.`<|a -> 1, b -> 2, b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5, c -> 2|>` evaluates to `<|a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> 2, d -> 5|>`.

Comment: association data struct is like a dictionary in other languages. There is no "first" or "second" or "last", etc.. in association. i.e. there is no order implied.  So what you say find the "last" item, then the question itself is not well posed. You can convert association to normal list using the command `Normal`.

Comment: @Nasser: Well, there _is_ an ordering of the keys in an association (see `KeySort`) and you can do `asso[[2]]` for getting the value of the second key. But doing this is typically asking for trouble... =)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I was thinking of the values itself. From [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Paper_1/Fundamentals_of_data_structures/Dictionaries)  "Items in a dictionary are accessed by key and are unordered." And then read that https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html  says "Associations provide generalizations of .... dictionaries," So that is what I meant. I was thinking of the data itself (values) not keys. That is what I understood by question above when it said "duplicate item".

Comment: @Nasser I meant my comment more as an addition to your comment, not as criticism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 10.1 and using a plain List of Rules in the input:

```
Merge[{a -> 1, b -> 2, b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5, c -> 2}, First]
Merge[{a -> 1, b -> 2, b -> 3, a -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5, c -> 2}, Last]
```

> ```
> <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 4, d -> 5|>
> <|a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> 2, d -> 5|>
> ```